# Creating column that is a proportion of two conditions

Tags: r

I have a data frame with about 50 variables but where the ones in the example under are the most important. My aim is to create a table that includes various elements split by department and gender. The combination of dplyr, group_by and summarise gives me most of what I need but I haven't been able to figure out how to get separate columns that shows for example meanFemaleSalary/meanMaleSalary per department. I'm able to get the mean salary per gender per department in separate data frames, but either get an error or just a single value when I try to divide them.

I have tried searching the site and found what I believed was similar questions but couldn't get any of the answers to work. I'd be grateful if anyone could give me a hint on how to proceed…
Thanks!

Example:

```
library(dplyr)
x <- data.frame(Department = rep(c("Dep1", "Dep2", "Dep3"), times=2),
                Gender = rep(c("F", "M"), times=3),
                Salary = seq(10,15))
```

This is what I have that actually works so far:

```
Table <- x %>% group_by(Department, Gender) %>% summarise(Count = n(),
                                                          AverageSalary = mean(Salary, na.rm = T),
                                                          MedianSalary = median(Salary, na.rm = T))
```

I'd like two additional columns for AvgSalaryWomen/Men and MedianSalaryWomen/Men.
Again thanks!

Comment: Can u show the expected output

Comment: In your example, there is only one row per each group

Comment: @Economist shows your expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the new columns to be part of `Table` you could do something like this. But it will result in the value being repeated per department.

```
Table %>% group_by(Department) %>% 
    mutate(`AvgSalaryWomen/Men` = AverageSalary[Gender == "F"]/AverageSalary[Gender == "M"],
           `MedianSalaryWomen/Men` = MedianSalary[Gender == "F"]/MedianSalary[Gender == "M"])

# Department Gender Count AverageSalary MedianSalary `AvgSalaryWomen/Men` `MedianSalaryWomen/Men`
# <fct>      <fct>  <int>         <dbl>        <int>                <dbl>                   <dbl>
# 1 Dep1       F          1           10.           10                0.769                   0.769
# 2 Dep1       M          1           13.           13                0.769                   0.769
# 3 Dep2       F          1           14.           14                1.27                    1.27 
# 4 Dep2       M          1           11.           11                1.27                    1.27 
# 5 Dep3       F          1           12.           12                0.800                   0.800
# 6 Dep3       M          1           15.           15                0.800                   0.800
```

If you want just one row per department simply change `mutate` to `summarise` and you'll get

```
# Department `AvgSalaryWomen/Men` `MedianSalaryWomen/Men`
#   <fct>                     <dbl>                   <dbl>
# 1 Dep1                      0.769                   0.769
# 2 Dep2                      1.27                    1.27 
# 3 Dep3                      0.800                   0.800
```

Comment: Thanks Relasta! That worked perfectly on my example data!  
When trying it out on my real data I got the following error message:
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) :   
  Column `AvgSalaryWomen/Men` must be length 1 (the group size), not 0



I'm guessing it must be something wrong with the formats of my table.  

Sorry for not showing expected output.

Comment: Maybe in some of your department groups you have one of the `Gender` groups missing? I removed the `Dep3` `M` row from your example data and got the same error message when I tried to rerun my code

Comment: Yes, that must be it. Thanks for the tip. I'll go through the data again.  I'm a total newbie at R but I guess that is pretty evident...

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option to get this by `spread`ing it to wide format

```
library(tidyverse)
x %>%
  spread(Gender, Salary) %>%
  group_by(Department) %>%
  summarise(`AvgSalaryWomen/Men` = mean(F)/mean(M), 
           `MedianSalaryWomen/Men` = median(F)/median(M))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
#    Department `AvgSalaryWomen/Men` `MedianSalaryWomen/Men`     
#    <fctr>                    <dbl>                   <dbl>
# 1 Dep1                      0.769                   0.769
# 2 Dep2                      1.27                    1.27 
# 3 Dep3                      0.800                   0.800           `
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to end up with a table that has one row per department and includes all of the descriptive statistics you're computing along the way, you probably need to convert to long, unite some columns to use as a key, go back to wide, and then add your ratios. Something like...

```
Table <- x %>%
  group_by(Department, Gender) %>%
  summarise(Count = n(),
            AverageSalary = mean(Salary, na.rm = TRUE),
            MedianSalary = median(Salary, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  # convert to long form
  gather(Quantity, Value, -Department, -Gender) %>%
  # create a unified gender/measure column to use as the key in the next step 
  unite(Set, Gender, Quantity) %>%
  # go back to wide, now with repeating columns by gender
  spread(Set, Value) %>%
  # compute the department-level quantities you want using those new cols
  mutate(AverageSalaryWomenMen = F_AverageSalary/M_AverageSalary,
         MedianSalaryWomenMen = F_MedianSalary/M_MedianSalary)
```